# Android:Not sure why my method isnt returning ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask

Hey my problem is that in my AsyncTask method doInBackground I have defined a return type of `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` and in my code I then return menuItems which is type `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`. I have seen a similar situation where it said that not all exits support the return `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` but looking at my code I cant see where I return anything other than `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` any help would be greatly apppreciated. Here is my code for doInBackground

```
protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String...petrolPriceURL){

                 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            {

                for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){


                    publishProgress(1);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


                String urlString = petrolPriceURL.toString();
                String result = "";
                InputStream anInStream = null;
                int response = -1;
                URL url = null;

                try {
                    url = new URL(urlString);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    return null;
                }
                URLConnection conn = null;
                try {
                    conn = url.openConnection();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    return null;
                }

                // Check that the connection can be opened
                if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
                    try {
                        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        return null;
                    }
                try
                {
                    // Open connection
                    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                    httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                    httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                    httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    httpConn.connect();
                    response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                    // Check that connection is OK
                    if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                    {
                        // Connection is OK so open a reader 
                        anInStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
                        InputStreamReader in= new InputStreamReader(anInStream);
                        BufferedReader bin= new BufferedReader(in);

                        // Read in the data from the RSS stream
                        String line = new String();
                        while (( (line = bin.readLine())) != null)
                        {
                            result = result + "\n" + line;
                            Log.v(TAG, "index=" + result);

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                        try {
                            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        Handler parser = new Handler();
                        String xml = result.toString(); // getting XML
                        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

                        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_FUEL);
                        // looping through all item nodes <item>
                        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(KEY_HIGHEST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_HIGHEST));
                            map.put(KEY_AVERAGE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_AVERAGE));
                            map.put(KEY_LOWEST, "Rs." + parser.getValue(e, KEY_LOWEST));
                            map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            menuItems.add(map);
                        }
                        return menuItems;
                }
            }

       }
```

The error I am getting is

```
This method must return a result of type ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>  PetrolPriceActivity.java    /PetrolpriceTestProject/src/org/me/myandroidstuff   line 78
```

reevaluated code:

```
 @Override
protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String...petrolPriceURL) {

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        publishProgress(1);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    String urlString = petrolPriceURL.toString();
    String result = "";
    InputStream anInStream = null;
    int response = -1;
    URL url = null;

    try {
        url = new URL(urlString);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return null;
    }
    URLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return null;
    }

    // Check that the connection can be opened
    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) {
        try {
            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            return null;
        }
    }

    try {
        // Open connection
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();
        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        // Check that connection is OK
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            // Connection is OK so open a reader
            anInStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader in= new InputStreamReader(anInStream);
            BufferedReader bin= new BufferedReader(in);

            // Read in the data from the RSS stream
            String line = new String();
            while (( (line = bin.readLine())) != null) {
                result = result + "\n" + line;
                Log.v(TAG, "index=" + result);


                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                Handler parser = new Handler();
                String xml = result.toString(); // getting XML
                Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_FUEL);
                // looping through all item nodes <item>
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(KEY_HIGHEST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_HIGHEST));
                    map.put(KEY_AVERAGE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_AVERAGE));
                    map.put(KEY_LOWEST, "Rs." + parser.getValue(e, KEY_LOWEST));
                    map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    menuItems.add(map);
                    return menuItems;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        try {
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //return menuItems;
}
```

Comment: You only return a `List` if an `IOException` occurs...

Comment: 1st of all your code should gv compile time exception as i can c the are two `{` when the code begins. Also after your thread sleep time is over from inside your 1st `try` block you are not returning anything.Your last return statement in the code is from within your `catch` block

Comment: Deb is my code not outwith my catch block....

Comment: catch (IOException ex)
                {
                        try {
                            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

Comment: is this not my catch block ended? wait i think i see what u mean. ill try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return anything in the `try {}` block :

```
try {
                // Open connection
                HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConn.connect();
                response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                // Check that connection is OK
                if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                {
                    // Connection is OK so open a reader
                    anInStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader in= new InputStreamReader(anInStream);
                    BufferedReader bin= new BufferedReader(in);

                    // Read in the data from the RSS stream
                    String line = new String();
                    while (( (line = bin.readLine())) != null)
                    {
                        result = result + "\n" + line;
                        Log.v(TAG, "index=" + result);

                    }
                }
            }
```

Which means that if no `IOException` is raised, nothing is returned.

Seems that you got too much logic in your `catch (IOException ex)` clause which may indicate that you should refactor your code (try getting the whole `menuItems` thing out of this catch clause).

---

Edit following reevaluated code :

Let's take a look at your last try-catch blocks which is also the end of your method :

```
try {
        // Open connection
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;

        // remainder omitted

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        try {
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //return menuItems;
```

In the try block you do return `menuItems` (of type `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`) but you do it **within** a for loop which will end up with the loop iterating exactly once before returning the `menuItems` object to the caller, ending the method call (and since it's probably not what you want, you should get that `menuItems` out of the for loop).

Then think about what will happen if an IOException get thrown *before* the `menuItems` object is returned (can't happen after) ? The exception will be caught in you catch clause where you throw another exception just to catch it immediately after to print the current stack trace and then... **nothing**. The function would end without returning anything which is exactly what the compiler complains about.

So you should find a way to get the `menuItems` returned no matter what (hint : since java variables are block-scoped, getting the `menuItems` declaration out of the for loop might not be enough. But you were on the good track with your last code line !)

Comment: this code is simply for getting the result value. The next part of the code is where everything comes together. I am trying to return menuItems. Before this feature was edited i did return result. The code after this example is where im looking for a return

Comment: Yes I see that you're looking for the result value within this try block but you either need to make it returns something of type ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> or you need to continue a *normal* program flow (where no IOException are thrown within this try block) and eventually returns something of type ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> (or re-throw the caught exception to the caller).

Comment: ive changed my code in my edit of my question.Now ive added my below code to the try. How exactly would i make this work? a example to help me understand would be appreciated

Comment: No I think you inadvertently tried to edit my answer. Please edit your question and I'll be glad to take a look.

Comment: No problem. Just a quick question, are you using an IDE like Eclipse or IntellijIdea ? I find your code weirdly formatted and as stated by Deb, you have some useless code blocks floating around your method. This indentation is error-prone and I suggest you clean it up a bit. I'll do an edit of the code in your question to show you what I meant.

Comment: Okay yeh i use eclipse i find my code is strangely indented too but i didnt realise i guess how much of a problem this can cause. That would be great thanks

Comment: Yeah usually we tend not to care much at the beginning but it's a problem which can quickly come out of hand with all those '{' and '}' so I think you should take extra care about that ;) I'll edit my answer to help you out.

Comment: also where abouts in my code should my return go. Having it in the try block hasnt got rid of the error and adding it to the line that is suggested then causes an error in menuItems saying that the menuItems cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: I edited my answer to get you on track ;) But I think you should read more about exception handling because some idioms you use are really weird. For example, they're practically no use to catch an exception and to re-throw an exception of the same type just to re-catch it afterwards. You should take an hour to practice with this lesson (and everything will become clear ;)) : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: sorry so should i return the menuItems variable in my exception too?

Comment: Maybe yes ! But what will happen if you try so ? The variable is out of scope since it was declared in another block (the try block). So where should you declare the variable for it to be accessible in your catch block ?

Comment: ive edited my code with what i think is the correct response.

Comment: Ah yes great, you found the solution ! It was indeed to declare the menuItems object *out* of the try block so that you can return it anywhere later in the method :)

Comment: thanks very much m4rtin you have been a great help so ive upvoted and declared your response as the answer